# What can a patent troll win by suing an open-source foundation e.g. GTK foundation?

Tags: gpl, lgpl, patents

Do open-source foundations have oodles and piles of cash lying around for patent trolls to scoop up?

Are open-source softwares licensed under the GPL not immune to patent trolls since there is no profit motive?

Answer (score 1):

One directly infringes a patent by making, selling, offering for sale, importing or using it. An open source foundation generally does not do these things. But it likely does encourage others to make, use, etc. technology that it essentially distributes. That can be an indirect infringement classed as contributory infringement or active inducement of infringement.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly sure that the OSS "foundations" are all [non-profit organisations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonprofit_organization) that collect funds to pay for site hosting and put extra money into paying developers for their time, this would leave little for any troll to collect.

Note that [GPLv3](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html) section 11 specifies that a contributor grants a *royalty-free patent license* which should prevent a patent troll from suing.

Comment: The patent license in the GPL is not really relevant here. In this case, the patent holder (i.e., troll) has no relation to the copyrighted code licensed under the GPL. The patent holder is claiming that the code written by someone else infringes on a patented system. The author of the copyrighted work does not hold the relevant patent and so cannot license it.

Comment: @apsillers The GPL states that the **contributor** grants the patent license, making the person submitting the infringing code (_should be_) the target of the troll, not the foundation owning the project. The foundation received the contribution in good faith that it was not patent infringing.

Comment: @sambler The patent troll will target whoever is distributing the code and if it is a troll obviously it will target whoever is more likely to pay a settlement.

Comment: What if the programmer who contributed the code had no idea there was a patent that could apply? Doesn't patent infringement require an intention to infringe for the patent holder or troll to collect?

Comment: Also, doesn't this idea that the author could be liable militate for all open source software to be anonymously written and put into the public domain?

Comment: @eonnu If you willfully infringe a patent, then normally it makes the damages higher. Anyway, the person who incorporates the infringing software into a product and sells that product is going to be the target of any lawsuit, because that's where the damages are. For example, if you are just a hobbyist developer and you just post some software on a Github page, for example, then there is probably only a 0.001% that a patent troll is going to get damages out of you. Instead they will wait until a big company uses that software, and then they will go after that company.